# Fedora 20, HD4400 OpenGL version

Tags: opengl, glsl, fedora20

My problem is updating Core and GLSL version of OpenGL. I installed newest Intel drivers for my HD 4400 and still got GLSL 1.30. Thing is, this GPU should support OpenGL/GLSL 4.0. No matter what I do, it seems it can't be upgraded and glxinfo still displays 1.30 GLSL. Any help with this from anyone who had similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glxinfo` reporting GL 3.0/GLSL1.30 is fine for this GPU. You are using the [Mesa3D](http://www.mesa3d.org/) open source OpenGL implementation. This does currently support OpenGL up to version 3.3. However, it only does support modern GL for *core profiles* only (and which is the only profile they are required to proovide, as by the spec). In compatibiliy mode, it is limited to GL 3.0 / GLSL 1.30 - and that is what you see here.

Old versions of `glxinfo` do not know about core profiles at all, and are limited to compatibility/legacy contexts. More recent versions of `glxinfo` will report both. So for an Intel HDxxxx GPU on Linux, you will get an output similiar to

```
$ glxinfo | grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.0.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.0.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```